# SVM taking too much time to train

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model

I'm trying to train my ML model with Svm.svc from sklearn, but it is taking so much time, it won't even train for once. This happens only when kernel function is used.

Currently i selected 10 Features for my model to train,
my model setting is,

```
SupportVectorMachineModel=svm.SVC(C=1,
                              kernel='poly',
                              gamma=1)
```

Kernel function should take time longer than usual but this feels unusual since my data set only have 360 around samples which is not much as well.

Any ideas? suggestions?

My Processor is Core i5, 1.6Ghz.
(RAM:16g)

Comment: Check that the data you're feeding the model makes sense and is processed correctly.

Comment: @m13op22 Guess you are on point. Even-though my discrete features were  encoded as well(1 or two of them are not), still the issue occurred, but it is a later while that I recalled yesterday that I forgot to normalize the data, as soon as normalized, now the whole process takes only milliseconds, but still it is a huge gap, like 30+ mins down to around 1 seconds. Do you have any feedback or ideas on this?..  I mean, feels like there had been a big blockage at the last time...maybe need to check out the features again? encode the UN-encoded ones as well?... it gains accuracy 80%+ as well...